# Rails Delayed job workers crash due to malformed yml in handler

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, backgroundworker, delayed-job

In the Rails application(Rails: 5.1, Ruby: 2.5.7, Mysql), the current design pushes the csv import operation to be executed in background by Delayedjobs. Due the size limitation of handler(text) the content is partially stored and when workers try to execute the job, they crash and the job never gets cleared automatically though it's set to max attempts=3.
This failure blocks the entire pipeline and keeps everything in pending state. Mysql version is 5.7
[image]

With the data payload when this operation is performed locally then the job is gracefully cleared with no crash in cases of malformed yml present in handler, mysql version is 5.6. What could be the issue here, any pointers please?

Comment: How are you enqueueing the job? A long time ago when I used DJ, I used to send ids, or just simple info as params to DJ to avoid such issues. Then in the job I'd fetch the user from the db based on the params the job has.

Comment: @razvans i'm saving the entire request params in handler and later using this value to execute operations